# Any help on how to use iptables to postroute to eth0:2 alias in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, routing, iptables, openvpn

On my server I want to route my internet traffic over my `eth0:2` alias. When I use this command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.4 -o eth0:2 -j MASQUERADE
```

It returns this:

```
Warning: weird character in interface `eth0:2' (No aliases, :, ! or *).
```

Is there any way to route only traffic from openvpn ip 10.8.0.4 over that single ip?

Thanks for you help,

Comment: I don't think it really makes sense to specify an interface alias here; the packets are going out over the same physical card either way, you just need to make sure they have the correct source / destination IPs and ports.

Answer (score 2):

You should use SNAT instead of MASQUERADE here.

```
MASQUERADE
   This target is only valid in the nat table, in the  POSTROUTING  chain.
   It  should  only  be used with dynamically assigned IP (dialup) connec‐
   tions: if you have a static IP address, you should use the SNAT target.
```

Assuming you want to SNAT any traffic coming from 10.8.0.4, exiting via eth0, onto whatever IP address is bound to eth0:2 (I'm going to say "w.x.y.z" here), try the following:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.4 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source w.x.y.z
```

where w.x.y.z is the IP bound to eth0.